# Merging two objects with respect to face

Tags: modifiers, objects, faces

I'm new enough to Blender to not really know how to ask this question, so bear with me. I thought I would do something "easy" - I have the interior dimensions of a box, so I started by making two of the walls and lining them up at the corner with a wide face of one against the narrow face of another:

[image: Two walls]
[image: Corners aligned]

I first tried using a Boolean Union to merge these into one object, but by the time I get to the third wall, the walls start disappearing. I also think that the union left a face inside the two walls, where I was hoping to get one solid object (mesh?).

As a second attempt I tried to use Join to merge them, but again I get faces left over inside the new object and when I used Boolean Union on the joined object later (with some other object) some of the walls would disappear.

So the question is, is there a way to align two objects as I have done and create one single solid object without all the leftover interior geometry (faces)? Hope that makes sense.